# Drop list (in list) elements/dataframe rows by column comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am struggling with a problem for a while now. I have a list consisting of other lists which looks like this when printed element by element:

```
[120, 2, 'germany']
[122, 1, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
[122, 1, 'germany']
[120, 2, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
```

I would like to drop the sublists which have the same value in the last "column" (index[2]), but only the ones that have a lower value in the middle "column" (index[1]) than the rows with the same last index[2]. No worries, I am aware that this is a list so far and has no actual columns. Hence, the output should like like:

```
[120, 2, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
[120, 2, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
```

I have tried multiple approaches so far, from single loops over simultaneous loops up to creating a copy of the list and iterate again. After a while, I have transformed the list into a pandas dataframe (although I will have to transform it back to list for further processing) and tried several methods again, without success so far.

The closest I got is:

```
dfList = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['ID',"status","country"])
dfList = dfList.groupby('country').filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1).drop_duplicates(subset=['country', 'status'], keep="first")
```

However, this will only provide me with each unique value within the dataframe. The difficulty lies in the fact that the code needs to be reusable with other values as well, hence I cannot filter with the actual values.

I would be very thankful for some thoughts or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
>>> (dfList.groupby('country', group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda g: g[g.status == g.status.max()])
           .sort_index())
    ID  status  country
0  120       2  germany
2  123       1   france
4  120       2  germany
5  123       1   france
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's with `transform` to get max status within each group:

```
dfList[
    dfList['status'].eq(
        dfList.groupby('country')['status'].transform('max'))]
```

Output:

```
    ID  status  country
0  120   2      germany
2  123   1      france 
4  120   2      germany
5  123   1      france
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code

```
data = [[120, 2, 'germany']
    , [122, 1, 'germany']
    , [123, 1, 'france']
    , [122, 1, 'germany']
    , [120, 2, 'germany']
    , [123, 1, 'france']]

d = {}

for i in data:
    if not d.__contains__(i[2]):
        d[i[2]] = i
    elif d[i[2]][1] < i[1]:
        d[i[2]] = i

for i in d.values():
    print(i)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think OP is working with a Pandas dataframe, not a 2d list. As an aside, you could use `i[2] in d` instead of `d.__contains__(i[2])` which isn't very idiomatic. Both blocks have the same action `d[i[2]] = i` so you could use `or` to join the predicates.

Comment: @ggorlen I think it's not exactly clear from the question itself. It is true that it is tagged `pandas`, but at the same time OP is saying that the data is *a list consisting of other lists*, so it seems somewhat ambiguous

Comment: @perl Not really--those are used to create the df in OP's example.

Comment: ...and if you look at *Hence, the output should like like: ...*, it's a list of lists again, not a DataFrame, so like I'm saying, it is not 100% clear

Comment: Indeed my question was not 100% clear. I have tried both ways, keeping it as a list of lists (which it was originally) or transforming it to a DF and then back to a list of lists. Many thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the question correctly, i can suggest this approach as a basis for your code

```
rows=[[120, 2, 'germany'],
[122, 1, 'germany'],
[123, 1, 'france'],
[122, 1, 'germany'],
[120, 2, 'germany'],
[123, 1, 'france']]


rd={}
for row in rows:
    if row[2] not in rd:
        rd[row[2]]=row[1]
        print(row)
    elif row[1] >= rd[row[2]]:
        rd[row[2]]=row[1]
        print(row)
```

The output will be

```
[120, 2, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
[120, 2, 'germany']
[123, 1, 'france']
```

just like you wanted

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion. However, it only works fine as long as the first list element in the list contains the higher value at [1]. Otherwise it will always print one element with a lower value.